# midori/ppa - can't never remove it?

Tags: apt, ppa, midori

I installed midori:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:midori/ppa
```

But it does not work on Ubuntu 17.10 so I have to remove it:

```
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:midori/ppa
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

Any idea why I can't remove it?

I have tried:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:midori/ppa
```

But still no luck.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

If I do this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:midori/ppa
```

I get:

```
 Midori Browser
    http://twotoasts.de/index.php/midori/

This PPA is signed. To add the GPG key to your apt keyring:
   sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A69241F1
Starting with Karmic, adding the PPA and its key is as simple as:
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:midori

You may also want to use the WebKit-team PPA:
     https://launchpad.net/~webkit-team/+archive/ppa
You can find unstable Midori versions at
    https://launchpad.net/~midori/+archive/midori-dev
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~midori/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel removing it.
```

It does not make sense!

Comment: What did `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:midori/ppa` say when you tried that?

Comment: @user535733 how do i get to `/etc/ap`??

Comment: @ByteCommander please see my edit.

Comment: And once you hit enter, what does it do then? Also, did you run `sudo apt update` afterwards? You need that to update your local software lists after removing the PPA.

Comment: @ByteCommander hitting enter and  `update` will give me the error - `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.`

Comment: You can not add Midori PPA let alone install Midori by `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:midori/ppa`, but `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:midori/ppa` should work, if the PPA supports your Ubuntu release (which it does not do).

Comment: Removing the repository by `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:midori/ppa` works at least in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, seems like you have to manually delete the repository, as `add-apt-repository` and `ppa-purge` seem to refuse touching it because it is not compatible with your Ubuntu release. It has seemingly been discontinued in 2015 with the last supported release being Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily).

To do that, you have to remove the sources list file `add-apt-repository` created when adding the PPA. I would expect it to be named like this, but it could also be slightly different:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/midori-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list
```

Open this (or however it is really named) file and verify that it is the correct one. It should contain only lines mentioning the repository URL from your error messages, i.e.

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu artful
```

If that is the case, you can delete the file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/midori-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list
```

After that, update your software lists with the new, changed configuration:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get `sudo: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/midori-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list: command not found`

Comment: Looks like you forgot the `rm`: It has to be `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/midori-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list`